# Nested for loops getting confusing especially their iterations

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I have this code and it outputs 0 0 and 1 if i input the number 3.

```
    num = int(input("Enter number"))
      for i in range(num):
        for j in range(i):
          print(j)
```

The problem is that I know it prints the first 0 because the range(0) prevents the for j code from executing on the first iteration of for i.  When i = 1 it obviously outputs 0 because it's the first iteration of J. But when i = 2, I know the j loop runs twice because range(2) but the thing is I'm confused why it's outputting 0 and 1 rather than 1 and 2 because it's the current iteration of J. Can Can anyone explain this problem and teach a little about nested for loops?

I tried the code and expected 0, 1, 2 but I got 0 0 1.

Answer (score 1):

Because EACH run of the `for j` loop starts over.  You are running three loops: one with `range(0)` which does nothing, one with `range(1)` which produces `0`, and one with `range(2)` which produces `0 1`.
It's the same as:

```
for i in range(3):
   print(list(range(i))
```